# want to convert json data in key value pair how to convert

Tags: apex, json

There is a custom Metadata (XYZ)and there is a field called Country_Currency__c in it and it holds json data
{
"USA" : "USD",
"INDIA" : "INR",
"CANADA" : "CAD",
"AUSTRALIA" : "USD"
}

Requirement: Get this json data into the apex class and put it into map in key value pairs

Comment: See other posts here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bjson%5D+parsing.

Answer (score 0):

use **deserializeUntyped(jsonString)** method that will deserialize the specified JSON string into collections of primitive data types.